# How to move a dictionary with object instances to another instance of its parent class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class, dictionary, instances, cloning

Perhaps I have the terminology wrong here, so this might have caused me not to have found an answer yet.

Here's the situation: I have an instance of the class clsSbkReach called FromReach. This instance has a dictionary that contains multiple instances of clsReachObject.

Now I want to move all existing reachobjects on FromReach to another instance of clsSbkReach, which is called ToReach. How can I achieve this? Here's what I do right now, but it seems to destroy all instances of clsSbkReachObject.

```
For Each myObject As clsSbkReachObject In FromReach.ReachObjects.Values
    ToReach.ReachObjects.ReachObjects.Add(myObject.ID.Trim.ToUpper, myObject)   'add the objects to the new reach
Next myObject
FromReach.ReachObjects.ReachObjects.clear
```

I really need to move the existing instances, not copy or clone.

Comment: A `Dictionary` contains keys as well as values. Do you want to move all the keys and values from one `Dictionary` to the other?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can move items from one `Dictionary` to another like this:

```
For Each key In sourceDictionary.Keys
    destinationDictionary.Add(key, destinationDictionary(key))
Next

sourceDictionary.Clear()
```